# Hard disk does not stop working

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive

As you can see, there is no "disc read/write" activity, but it is at 100% of highest active time. The notebook is unusable (as you can see on picture, I was not even able to save it, so I had to take picture).

If I turn off wi-fi button at my notebook and start it, it works fine.
When I turn this wi-fi button on, then happens what you can see on picture below.

I tried to "let it work" for several hours, but nothing happend.

Restarting does not help.

I have windows 7.

[image: my diagnostic]

Comment: This normally means the drive is failing and spending all the time trying to write data

Comment: But why it does work correctly until I turn wi-fi on?

Comment: With the Wi-Fi on, what app is using the network?

Comment: You have not provided information required to answer either question

Comment: You should check the error logs.  My_Computer->Manage-> Logs. There may be a clue in them.

Comment: @JulianKnight - there is none, I watched network-traffic and it is at zero level.

Comment: hahaha a photo of screenshot in paint... classic! :)

Comment: Does it behave the same way in Safe Mode? Have you tried removing and reinstalling your suspected WiFi drivers?

Comment: Good chance it is infected & trying to send information out via the Wifi connection.

Comment: @techie007 - how I said, I was not able to save it, because of nonstop disc activity, thats why I had to take photo :). But good point with removing and reinstalling wi-fi drivers. I give it a try.